# Zsh glob: Get everything except stuff in a certin folder

Tags: zsh

Trying to find all files except those inside `vendor/` folders, but why is this failing?

```
setopt extendedglob

for file in **/*~vendor/; do
done
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this does what you're looking for:

```bash
setopt extendedglob
print -l ^vendor/**/*(.)
```

---

The `*~` negation syntax usually needs parentheses in order to determine where the expression after the tilde ends. Your pattern is requesting all files and folders except those where the glob result name ends with `vendor/`. The glob result never includes the trailing slash, so you end up with all of the files and folders.

Adding parens will change the behavior of that pattern, but probably not in a useful way. This will result in a list of all of the directories where the last component is not `vendor`:

```bash
print -l **/(*~vendor)/
```

so `x/y`, `x/y/vendor/z`, and `vendor/a` will be included, but `x/y/vendor` will not.

The parentheses limit the 'not' pattern to just one piece of the path. In order to exclude matches at the top-level, the tested component needs to be at the front of the pattern:

```bash
print -l (*~vendor)/**/*
```

The very first pattern above uses the `^` syntax to produce the same  results. The `(.)` glob qualifier in that pattern limits the globbing to plain files, so directories are not included.

---

Another variation that may be useful - this will exclude directories that have any component named `vendor`. It is similar to `find -prune`:

```bash
print -l (^vendor/)#*(.)
```

This will produce a list of all files except those in subdirectories with names like `vendor/x`, `a/vendor` and `a/vendor/b`.